# Sentry still shows unmodified stack trace but no error is being shown

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sentry, source-maps

Im currently trying to get Sentry to work in an Angular 5 web app. Errors are being reported and show up on in Sentry the stack traces however are still minified.

Currently the sentry-cli is being used inside a Bitbucket pipeline to inject debug ids and upload the source maps to Sentry as I don't want to get into Angulars way of using Webpack. Releases have the "1.2.3" format and the "dist is a normal number from the bitbucket pipeline
(`BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`)

I had a couple of errors regarding the matching of artefacts and events but I thought I worked it all out as I get nothing reported anymore, at least from Sentry front end. When I use the `sentry-cli sourcemaps explain` command I get following output:

```
✔ Fetched data for event: 98d411xxxx5b6e09
✔ Event has release name: 1.12.6
✔ Event has a valid exception present
✔ Event has a valid stacktrace present
⚠ Exception is already source mapped and first resolved frame points to:


> {snip} ket(n,t)},n.prototype.throwError=function(){throw new Error("test developers page error")},n}(),mt=function(){},vt=function(n,t){var e=this; {snip}
  !function(){try{var e="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:{},n=(new Error).sta {snip}
  //# debugId=5d1feccd-23cf-5xxxx7f2402
  //# sourceMappingURL=main.36890956xxxb8503c71.bundle.js.map
```

In Sentry you see pretty much the same as the snippet above. I wasn't able to get too much information about this particular warning on the web and im unsure what it's actually trying to tell me. Did somebody run into similar problems or did even try to get Sentry to work in Angular 5?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm seeing the same message "Exception is already source mapped and first resolved frame points to:"...

Comment: @RichardScarrott Nope, sadly not. Didn’t put any more effort into it.